# How does a neural network produce an array?

Tags: neural-network

## Background

I've been studying Neural Networks, specifically the implmentation provided by this incredible [online book](http://www.neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com). In the example network provided, we're shown how to create a neural network that classifies the [MNIST training data](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) to perform [Optical Character Recognition (OCR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition).

The network is configured so that the input stimuli represents a discrete range of thresholded pixel data from a 24x24 image; at the output, we have ten signal paths which represent each of the different solutions for the input images; these are used classify a handwritten digit from zero to nine. In this implementation, a handwritten '3' would drive a strong signal down the third output path.

Now, I've seen that Neural Networks can be applied to far more *'unpredictable'* output solutions; for example, take the team who taught a network to recognize the hair on a human:

[image: Using a neural network to classify regions of hair on an image.]

## Question

Surely in the application above, we couldn't use a fixed output array length because the number of points that would qualify within an image would vary just so wildly between different samples. Can anyone recommend what kind of pattern would have been used to accomplish this?

## Assumption

In the interest of completeness, I'm going to propose that the team could have employed a kind of 'line following robot' for the classification task. So for an input image, a network could be trained by using a small range of discrete commands (`LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `UP`, `DOWN`) for a fixed period `t` and train the network to control the robot like an *[Etch-a-Sketch](http://scinewsjou-242d.kxcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/algorithm.png)*.

Alternatively, we could implement a network which would map pixels one-to-one, and define whether individual pixels contributed to hair; but this wouldn't be compatible with different image resolutions.

So, do either of these solutions sound plausable? If so, are these basic implementations of a known generic solution for this kind of problem? What approach would you use?

Comment: You could just classify every pixel separately based on its neighbourhood

Comment: @harold So you'd iterate the image using a fixed size window and train an algorithm for representing fixed regions of hair?